# Copy multiple files using Powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I copy all files of kind:docx from all directories under and including e.g. D:\Doc_Source, to destination E:\Doc_Destination, in batches of e.g. 500, and only when there are none left in E:\Doc_Destination, except if they have string 'somestring' in the filename..?

I **really** appreciate any help I'm gonna get on this - I'm very new to PowerShell and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> except if they have string 'somestring' in the filename..?

I assume you want to exclude based on file name, if so change $exclude="text" to equal what you want to exclude.

```
$source="D:\Doc_Source"
$dest="E:\Doc_Destination"
$ext="*.docx"
$exclude="text"

$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse $source -Filter $ext | Where-Object {$_.Name -NotMatch $exclude}

ForEach ($file in $files) {
    Copy-Item -Path $file.Fullname -Destination $dest -Force 
}
```

Comment: Just realized I missed the batches portion, this will copy all files at once.  I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: Are you looking to copy 500 then pause ?

Comment: I guess CHECK if DESTINATION has ZERO, then COPY 500 and PAUSE, and CHECK if DEST.....

Comment: Anyone else able to add to the work CML started?